# Moving from VB.Net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, resources

I'm seriously considering moving from VB.Net to C#.  If you made the jump to C# from vb.net, then what were the best resources you used to learn the language going from novice to pro?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757518/good-exercises-to-transition-from-coding-in-vb-net-to-c/1757558#1757558

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660177/c-programming-tutorial-websites

Answer (score 16):

I use this [VB.NET C# comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) reference all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Oddly this **reverse** question might help you understand the areas in which things differ.

If C# programmers need to be told certain things then there must be a difference to the way VB.NET works:

[What a C# Coder Should Know Before They Write VB](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kathleen/archive/2008/07/25/what-a-c-coder-should-know-before-they-write-vb-updated.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe one of the best things to do is to rewrite some of your VB code, some classes, i was a vb coder some time ago, and one of the things i did was write the NerdDinner App in C#, following the Scott Gu tutorial it really help me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know Visual Basic .Net, you will not have much difficulty on learning C#

Besides other posts Visual Basict .Net to C# converter will help you too much.

You can write your code in Visual Basic .Net and see the equivalent in C#

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 2):

OJT worked for me.  the framework is the same.  Syntax is "just another language" to learn.  People get hung up on "what langauage" far too often.  Skills I learned as an assembly language programmer are just as valid in higher-level languages.

The VB editor in Visual Studio does have some nice features.

Answer (score 2):

[Programming C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527438) is a great reference.

You'll struggle with the syntax (End versus curly brace and semicolons), but the transition should be somewhat smooth. It's just understanding the differing syntax which will make it frustrating.

[Choosing between C# and VB.NET](http://www.dnjonline.com/article.aspx?ID=mar05_vbvscsharp)

> The only major difference between the
> two languages is that C# can break out
> of the ‘managed’ world of .NET to
> support unsafe code should this be
> required. However unsafe code is, as
> its name suggests, inherently
> hazardous and you may feel that it is
> a good thing to avoid using it.
> Explicit use of pointers is seldom
> required when programming .NET. If you
> really feel that you cannot do without
> pointers, then C# would be a good
> choice of language. If you are happy
> to work within the managed world of
> .NET, then C# or VB.NET would be
> equally suitable for your purposes.
>
> Of course, there are other .NET languages available too. At first
> sight, C++ might seem the most
> attractive choice for programmers with
> previous experience of that language.
> You need to be aware, however, that
> the .NET version of C++ is best used
> for manipulating unmanaged memory. In
> most cases, C# would be a better
> choice of .NET language for a
> programmer with C++ experience. Unlike
> C++, the C# language was specifically
> designed for the .NET Framework. It
> benefits from a simple syntax, garbage
> collection and type safety to
> eliminate many potential bugs.

Answer (score 2):

In pre .net days, there was a real perception (and deservedly so)  of VB being for kids and the C languages being for grown ups. The .net Framework has changed (the reality if not the perception of) all that. I don't recall seeing anything in c# that couldn't be done in VB. I don't do VB very much so I don't remember irritating things about the language, in c# two pet peeves for me are the case sensitivity and the syntax of the for loop. Neither of which apply to the VB language. So the question is, are you sure you need to change?

Comment: Widespread bias against VB.NET may not be logical, but it does exist.  Since the move to C# is largely trivial, why not do it and benefit from the improved perception (logical or not) of your seriousness and skill level?

Comment: First, I would not call learning a new language trivial. Not learning, as in put it on your resume and charge people big bucks per hour. Secondly, a developer's "seriousness" and skill level is not derived exclusively or even predominantly from his/her skill in any one language, but in how well he/she can think. If you are dealing with someone who does not believe this, then you really have a completely different problem.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason why one must move from VB.NET to C#.NET or vice versa. They both utilize the same framework api and tools. So, I find no point in migrating from VB.NET to C#.NET or vice versa.